# Is it possible to remove the word "date" from archives?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, archives

I can't figure out how to remove the word "date from the permalink for yearly archives. For example:

[http://localhost/wordpress/news/date/2012]

On single news pages the permalink looks like this:

[http://localhost/wordpress/news/2012/news-article/]

I've created a custom post type called "News". The slug for this post_type is obviously "news". I've set 'archive' to true and 'with_front' to false.

I want a clean News Archive which can be broken down by years. I tried a different solution, but it posed problems. I set the 'archive' to false and created a News page with a custom template, for current News Articles. I then created child pages for each year's News Articles, but Wordpress added -2 to the permalink.. For example:

2012 = news/2012-2

I just want my permalinks to be like this:

news

news/2012

news/2012/news-item

I've tried a few plugins but nothing seems to work. Any Ideas?

Comment: Do you have the %post_id% in your permalink structure somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

go to Settings -> Permalinks tab

Try this:

```
/%category%/%year%/%postname%/
```

Comment: I tried that. I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress Answers showed me a related question that helped.

[custom post types, wp_get_archives and add_rewrite_rule](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50530/custom-post-types-wp-get-archives-and-add-rewrite-rule)

I had to modify the code:

```
add_action('init', 'wpse50530_journal_archive_rewrite');
function wpse50530_journal_archive_rewrite(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^news/([0-9]{4})/?','index.php?post_type=news&year=$matches[1]','top');
}
```